# Vuex and routing - Redirection after sign in

Tags: api, vue.js, laravel-5.3, restful-url, vuejs2

I'm using vuex and laravel as backend for my project.

Redirection after signing in is not working. here is my code :

```
methods: {
    submit () {
      this.$validator.validateAll()
      if (!this.errors.any()) {
        this.$store.dispatch('SIGNIN', this.user)
        this.$router.push({name: 'chat'})
      }
    }
}
```

For Vuex :

```
actions: {
    SIGNIN (context, user) {
      context.commit('handleLoader')
      Vue.http.post(apiDomain + signInUrl, user, {headers: getHeaders})
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          Vue.auth.setToken(response.body.token)
          Vue.auth.setAuth(response.body.user)
          context.commit('handleLoader')
          // context.commit('navigateAfterSignIn')
        }
      })
    }
}
```

And my mutation

```
 mutations: {
    signin (state) {
      state.isLoggedIn = true
    }
  }
```

My routes :

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'chat',
      component: Chat,
      meta: {
        forAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/signin',
      name: 'signin',
      component: Signin,
      meta: {
        forVisitors: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/signup',
      name: 'signup',
      component: Signup,
      meta: {
        forVisitors: true
      }
    }
  ],
  mode: 'history'
})
```

And my check for routes protections

```
router.beforeEach(
  (to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.forVisitors)) {
      if (Vue.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        next({
          path: '/'
        })
      } else next()
    } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.forAuth)) {
      if (!Vue.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        next({
          path: '/signin'
        })
      } else next()
    } else next()
  }
)
```

How to redirect automatically?? 

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you using `vueRouter` if yes then can you put your `router.js` file?

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: But there is no **edited** tag on your question, are your sure?

Comment: It looks fine, is the control reaching the right `if-else` blocks?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that the side effect of navigation should be a part of the Vuex store action UNLESS you are 100% certain it will always need to happen as part of this action.  Wherever in the application you are doing this from should take care of that navigation.  To accomplish this you need to do two things

In your action, return the promise that is the Vue.http thing

Handle success with a .then in the component your are calling this from

```
//Store action, note Vue.http.post MUST return a thenable (Promise)
SIGNIN (context, user) {
  context.commit('handleLoader')
  return Vue.http.post(apiDomain + signInUrl, user, {headers: getHeaders})
    .then(response => { 
      handleSettingToken(response)
      return response 
    })
  } 
}

//Component

methods: {   
  handleLogin() {
    return store.dispatch(SIGNIN, user)
      .then(response => doNavigationHere(response)   
  }
}
```

Comment: it works :) i have used 'Promise'. this is the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40390411/vuex-2-0-dispatch-versus-commit