# How to fetch data from server in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am trying to fetch data from the server using Vue + Vuex + Vue resource.On button click I want to hit Http request and show in list format .I tried like that.Here is my code

https://plnkr.co/edit/EAaEekLtoiGPvxkmAtrt?p=preview

```
// Code goes here

var store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        Item: []
    },
    mutations: {
        getItems: function (state) {

        }

    },
    actions: {
        fetchData:function (context) {
            this.$http.get('/data.json', function(v1users)
                {
                   // this.$set('v1_user',v1users);
            });
        }
    }
})

var httprequest = Vue.extend({
    "template": '#http_template',
    data: function () {
        return {
            items: store.state.Item
        }
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData: function () {
          store.dispatch('fetchData')
        },

    }
})

Vue.component('httprequest', httprequest);

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#App',
    data: {},


})
```

;
any udpdate?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Vue.http.get` instead of `this.$http.get`.

Vuex doesn't have access to `$http` directly from instance.

Comment: could you please share plunker

Comment: how I will do that ?

Comment: No need for plunker.. Just please replace `this.$http.get` with `Vue.http.get` in your code. That's the only change you need to do.

Comment: I am able to fetch data .but how I will pass this data to component

Comment: You need to return promise in vues action. Here's some more details on how to to just that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165766/returning-promises-from-vuex-actions