# Vue js 2 - Callback function for an action dispatched in a component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, axios, vuex

Is there any way to know if the dispatched action from a component has completed or not without setting a state?
Right now I have an action - createAddress
In my component, I have a modal where the user enters address.
When the user enters the details and clicks on 'Save' button, I dispatch the action like this -

```
saveAddress () {
  this.$store.dispatch('createAddress', this.address)
}
```

The action makes an axios call and returns either status 200 OK or error.
If status 200 I want to close the modal. If error, I don't want to close it.
What is the best way to achieve this? Do I really have to create a state, update that state value, watch that value in the component and then close the modal?

Below is what I want from code point of view

```
saveAddress () {
  this.$store.dispatch('createAddress', this.address)
  // Close modal if success
}
```

Comment: I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165766/returning-promises-from-vuex-actions?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: The action should return a Promise

Answer (score 0):

```
saveAddress () {
  this.$store.dispatch('createAddress', this.address, this)
}
```

and in createAddress, you can close modal

Comment: don't do this! The action should return a Promise