# Is there a way to use promise in action with this structure Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have an action which fires on form submit in component

```
this.$store.dispatch('registerAction', this.registerData);
```

Also in this component I want to show message like "Registration is successful".
For that I want to listen for property in my `this.$store.state` `registerSuccess` which is false by default.

**registerAction (Vuex)**

```
  return this.api.registerUser()
       .then(response => {
          if(response.success) {
               return store.dispatch('registerSuccess');
          }
          return store.dispatch('registerFail');
       });
```

`registerSuccess` mutation sets `state.registerSuccess = true;` (and fail sets it to false)

**Question:**

How can I listen for changes to `state.registerSuccess` in this case? If I'm putting it in computed it returns false. Although it does change in Vuex store to `true`

```
computed: {
        registerSuccess() {
            console.log(this.$store.state.registerSuccess)
            return this.$store.state.registerSuccess;
        }
    },
```

Comment: Check this for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165766/returning-promises-from-vuex-actions

Comment: This might not be related to the answer, but why do you return the dispatches and not call it directly?

Comment: @JeremyWalters, there are a few good reasons to want to use store actions instead of hardcoding the API calls and callback directly inside a components: a) it makes the code more reusable, in case one would like to register a user from another component let's say, or b) it is easier to debug or maintain: if something goes wrong or a refactor is needed, you only need to update the store action.

Answer (score 1):

You've mentioned that `registerSuccess` is a `mutation` which also means that you have put it inside the `mutation` property inside your store object like this:

```
  {
    state: {
      registerSuccess: false
    },
    mutations: {
      registerSuccess(state) {
        state.registerSuccess = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

In that case, you would need to use [`commit()`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) to execute the `registerSuccess` mutation.

Your code should be:

```
return this.api.registerUser()
            .then(response => {
                if(response.success) {
                    return store.commit('registerSuccess');
                }
                return store.commit('registerFail');
            });
```

Comment: I usualy call my mutations from actions. So action `registerSuccess` looks like this for example `context.commit('REGISTER_SUCCESS', payload);` And in mutation `REGISTER_SUCCESS` a change my `state`. Sorry if my question was a bit confusing.