# Javascript - can't iterate through array of objects with images

Tags: javascript, arrays, image-processing, vue.js

I have difficulties with iterating through array of objects which contains image. As my code below shows the array in console looks kind of empty but when I open it in console, I see all this objects also with iteration numbers. I can't google and get to the point how to transform it into proper working array to make for in loop and iterate through it in Vue.js.
I attach you the code where comments says more than my description.

```
        const frameImage = [
        {
            url: 'http://www.realmadryt.pl/fotki/_up/newsy/lukamodric_165.png'
        },
        {
            url: 'http://www.realmadryt.pl/fotki/_up/newsy/florentinoperez_11.jpg'
        },
        {
            url: 'http://www.realmadryt.pl/fotki/_up/newsy/ramosbarkinsta1.jpg'
        },
        {
            url: 'http://www.realmadryt.pl/fotki/_up/newsy/lukamodric_165.png'
        },
        {
            url: 'http://www.realmadryt.pl/fotki/_up/newsy/florentinoperez_11.jpg'
        },
        {
            url: 'http://www.realmadryt.pl/fotki/_up/newsy/ramosbarkinsta1.jpg'
        },
    ];

    let createdImages = [];

    frameImage.forEach(item => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.src = item.url;
        image.onload = () => {
            // set image only when it is loaded
            createdImages.push({
                image,
                width: image.width,
                height: image.height,
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                draggable: true
            });
        };
    });
    console.log(createdImages)


    // nothing happens
    createdImages.forEach(item => {
        console.log(item)
    });

    //also nothing happens
    for(img in createdImages) {
        console.log(img);
    }

    //length is actually 0?
    console.log(createdImages.length)
```

Also jsFiddle: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/qruskmp4/2/)

Comment: Nothing is happening because you are looping over `createdImages` before the `onload` has fired and populated it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think that it is async operation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would map the array of URLs to an array of promises that resolve with your object when the image has loaded. Then use `Promise.all` to wait for them all to load (resolve). For example

```js
Promise.all(frameImage.map(({ url }) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const image = new Image()
  image.onload = () => resolve({
    image,
    width: image.width,
    height: image.height,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    draggable: true
  })
  image.onerror = reject
  image.src = src
}))).then(createdImages => {
  // now you can iterate
}).catch(err => {
  console.error('Could not load all images', err)
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have problem with returning these createdImages from my method. In a nuthsell createdImages should be returned from outer method which wraps this Promise, how can I achieve that? I know that I have to do it from .then() callback function but I have no idea how

Comment: Oh and I forgot to say that I am using Vue.js and this method is global in "eventBus" state and on my component I use computed property to render these images with v-for. Maybe you know better way to achieve that.

Comment: Yes, use Vuex. This sort of thing is perfect to put into an asynchronous _action_. See [Returning Promises from Vuex actions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40165766/283366)

Comment: Thanks, but it is not that big project and now I achieve what i want by watching computed property which fires when the global images state change and then I push converted state into component own imageArr, is it bad?