# Returning data from a Vuex action

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Can I return data from a Vuex action or do I need to update the store?

I've got an action defined but it returns no data:

```js
getData() {
    return { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }
}
```

Comment: hmm https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you mean Vuex actions?

Comment: Yes, I meant Vuex actions.

Comment: Duplicate question: [Returning Promises from Vuex actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165766/returning-promises-from-vuex-actions)

Comment: Don't do this, actions are not supposed to return values https://stackoverflow.com/a/74562954/836723

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually return data from an action. From [the documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#composing-actions):

> Actions are often asynchronous, so how do we know when an action is
> done? And more importantly, how can we compose multiple actions
> together to handle more complex async flows?

You should return a promise and the data in the `resolve()` method:

```js
actions: {
  actionA () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({ name: 'John Doe' })
      }, 1000)
    })
  }
}
```

And use it this way:

```js
store.dispatch('actionA').then(payload => {
  console.log(payload) /* => { name: 'John Doe' } */
})
```

Comment: I don't know if I misunderstood your question. I assumed yout ment Vuex actions and not the `data()` method in Vue.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to Vuex actions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work if the code that calls your action uses either 'await' or a callback.

For example:

```
const result = await store.dispatch('getData');
```

The main takeaway being that actions return promises even if the action isn't doing any asynchronous work!