# How to return a value from store (vuex) vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am working on a project (just personal) and trying to get a bit familiar with vuex. I managed to do a lot (so far) but there is one nut I cannot crack.

I am trying to access a field -> salary of a particular employee

Here is my store.js (vuex)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
      emps: [
              {name: 'John', salary: 110},
              {name: 'Jimmy', salary: 80}
      ],
  },
  getters: {
  },
  mutations: {
    getCurrentSalary: (state, data) => {
      var empIndex = findEmpIndex(data);
      console.log(state.emps[empIndex].salary); // this is ok!!
      return state.emps[empIndex].salary;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    getCurrentSalary: ({commit}, payload) => {
      commit('getCurrentSalary', payload);
    }
  }
});


// helpers
function findEmpIndex (stockName) {
   return store.state.markets.findIndex(item => item.name === stockName);
}
```

in a component of a particular employee, I am calling it as follows:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="container">
     Current Salary: {{ getCurrentSalary("John") }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {mapActions} from 'vuex'

  export default {
      methods: {
        ...mapActions([
          'getCurrentSalary'
        ])
      }
  }
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
</style>
```

But there is a catch that the salary can change so I want to get the change instantly (whenever it happens)

I can see the console log correctly (this at least means that function is being called .. but when printed it says:

```
Current Salary: [object Promise]
```

It doesn't want to print the value but prints a promise instead .. I did a lot of searching but didn't find (or maybe understand) how to fix this ... if there is any forum or question similar to this one with a solution please send a link (and sorry)

Comment: Don't do this, actions are not supposed to return values https://stackoverflow.com/a/74562954/836723

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I already solved it with getters :) the only trick was that to return a value (based on the passed parameter) is to return a function inside the getter :)

```
getters: {
    getSalary: (state, getters) => (empName) => {
      var empIndex = findEmpIndex(empName);
      return state.emps[empIndex].salary;
    }
  }
```

and calling it as follows (in the component):

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="container">
      Current Value: {{ getSalary(emps.name) }} 
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'

  export default {
      computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
          'getSalary'
        ])
      }
  }
</script>
```

and it reacts to the changes in the salary online/realtime :)

thx guys

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to get the return value of the `getCurrentSalary` **mutation**, but you're calling the `getCurrentSalary` **action** in your component.

Since you're trying to get data instead of changing data, I would suggest you remove the mutation and rather create a getter.

Something like:

```
  getters: {
    getCurrentSalary: (state) => (data) => {
      var empIndex = findEmpIndex(data);
      console.log(state.emps[empIndex].salary); // this is ok!!
      return state.emps[empIndex].salary;
    }
  },
```

And then use `mapGetters` instead of `mapActions` in your component.

Comment: I can't seem to make this work :(  I get `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'salary' of undefined"`

Answer (score 0):

I just want to say that your example is contrived and it won't work. Firstly, in your example, the store state is already populated which won't be the case unless an action to get the salary data is dispatched. If the action to get salary data is dispatched, you won't need the action to getCurrentSalary of each user as it's a matter of getting data from the store.

That being said, I will walk you through the process of using the Vuex store IF your example were "correct".

In your template, what you want is to dispatch an action when the component is created or mounted (using the `created` or `mounted` hook). I have a preference for the mounted hook so I will use it,

#### EmployeeComponent.vue

```js
<script>
  import {mapActions} from 'vuex'

export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      'getEmployeeSalaries'
    ])
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getEmployeeSalaries(); // dispatch action when component mounts. You want to get the updated salary of employees
  }
 }
</script>
```

You then proceed to commit a mutation in the action(like you have done). You are correct in changing the state in a mutation as according to the Vuex [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html),

> *The only way to actually change state in a Vuex store is by committing
> a mutation.*

The Vuex store is reactive just as the `data` property in your component, so if a state changes, the portion of the template with that state re-renders.

There are two ways to get state data.

- Get the state in the template. You can use `mapState` or `this.$store.state` to access state in the template. Then in a computed property, you alter the state and return it (if necessary). You need altered state in your case because you aren't returning the complete state of the employees array, but the salary of one employee.  (The example below is from the documentation)

```js
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

computed: {
  ...mapState({
    // map this.count to store.state.count
    'count'
  }),
  doneTodosCount () {
    return this.$store.state.todos.filter(todo => todo.done).length
  }
}
```

Like the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html) states, though, altering the store state in the component (using this.$store.state.. or using mapState AND then altering it) isn't ideal because:

> *If more than one component needs to make use of this, we have to
> either duplicate the function, or extract it into a shared helper and
> import it in multiple places - both are less than ideal.*

This brings me to the second way of getting state that is altered

- You can use getters in the store and then use `mapGetters` to access them in the template. Getters are ideal because as the documentation states:

> You can think of them as computed properties for stores. Like computed properties, a
> getter's result is cached based on its dependencies, and will only
> re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed.*

With a getter, (in this case, a current salary getter), you can use it anywhere else in the application without duplication or converting it to a helper function and importing it multiple times (as stated in the documentation).

#### Vuex Store

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    emps: [], // the state should be empty. The store cannot be populated without a mutation
  },
  getters: {
    currentSalaryOfUser: state => {  // this won't work in your example because store state is not being changed. The getter will only change when state.emps state changes. Just like a computed property in the vue instance.
      var empIndex = findEmpIndex(data);
      return state.emps[empIndex].salary; // you return the "altered" state (just the salary, instead of the whole state. If you are returning the whole state, it will be better to use mapState or this.$store.state to get the data.) which can be used in multiple cases if required, without duplication, as stated in the docs.
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    getCurrentSalary (state, payload) {
      // There is no state to mutate in your case. You are trying to get a salary state which is already updated by the getEmployeeSalaries action and mutation.
    },
    getEmployeeSalaries(state, payload) {
      // mutate state
      state.emps = payload; // this is what should happen. The employee salaries should be obtained in an action called getEmployeeSalaries (or any data you give it). Your example is contrived so it won't work.
    }
  }
  actions: {
    getCurrentSalary: ({commit}, payload) => {
      commit('getCurrentSalary', payload); // this is redundant in your case. You don't need it. If the example were a good one, you will just get the data from your state which is populated by the getEmployeeSalaries action and mutation
    },
    getEmployeeSalaries: async ({commit}) => { // there should be an action like this that is dispatched from your template. This will probably be an asynchronous action that gets data from the database

      const response = await databaseCallToFetchData; // wait for the data to be fetched from the database
      const payload = response.data.data // get the payload from the database call
      commit('getEmployeeSalaries', payload);
    }
  }
});
```

Then in your template:

#### EmployeeComponent.vue

```js
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    // mix the getters into computed with object spread operator
    ...mapGetters([
       'currentSalaryOfUser' // changed the name to avoid a clash with the getCurrentSalary action
    ])
  }
}
```

```html
<template lang="html">
  <div class="container">
     Current Salary: {{ currentSalaryOfUser }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: hello, thx for your "article" ... I really appreciate it ..  I wasn't able to make your solution work .. and there is one issue ->  I need to pass an argument to that function because I want to get a salary for a specific employee only ...

The other catch is, that the salary can change (I have a button in my application) which "increases the salary" ... thus, I wanted to get the current one (no matter whether populated or not at the beginning - this was just a demonstration)

Comment: hi, @Mr.P, what I am trying to tell you is that your solution cannot work. The reason it cannot work is because you are mutating state. How do you get the data in the store?