# Returning error from promise in vuex store action

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to set up a login action using Parser which returns an error if the authentification fails. Then I want to catch the errror and return it to the component where I display the error. However I always get an unhandled promise rejection.

I already tried different methods of rejecting or returning the error with no success.
        reject(error) (recommended here [Returning Promises from Vuex actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165766/returning-promises-from-vuex-actions))
        return reject(error)
        return Promise.reject(error)
        return Promise.reject(new Error(error))
or simply 
        return error

my actions:

```
actions: {
      login(vuexContext, authData) {
        console.log(authData.email)
        Parse.User.logIn(authData.email, authData.password)
          .then(user => {
            vuexContext.commit('SET_USER', user)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Actions login - Error: ' + error)
            reject(error)
          })
      }
```

my submit method:

```
onSubmit() {
      this.$store
        .dispatch('login', {
          email: this.formData.email,
          password: this.formData.password
        })
        .then(() => {
          // ..
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('Catching' + error)
          if (error.code == 101) {
            this.errorMsg = 'Email oder Passwort falsch'
          } else {
            this.errorMsg =
              'Entschuldigung, hier ist etwas schief gelaufen... Fehler: ' +
              error.message
          }
          this.showError = true
          this.$router.push('/sessions/new')
        })
    }
```

I would expect that the catch block in the onSubmit method catches the error .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to wrap the function return as a new promise.

```
actions: {
    login(vuexContext, authData) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(authData.email)
        Parse.User.logIn(authData.email, authData.password)
          .then(user => {
            vuexContext.commit('SET_USER', user)
            resolve()
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Actions login - Error: ' + error)
            reject(error)
          })
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is redundant `return Parse.User` is the same