# Implement a pop up box after a successful axios post

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have an action

```
storeExpense(context, params){
    axios.post('api/expenses', params)
    .then( response => {
        context.dispatch('getExpenses')
    })
    .catch( error => {
        context.commit('errors', error.response.data.errors)
        //console.log(error.response.data.errors);
    })
}
```

and then on my component when the user click the submit button I just called the action via dispatch

```
store(){
    this.$store.dispatch('storeExpense',this.expense)
}
```

Now i have [sweetalert](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) I'm confused how to implement it after a successful axios post request

I tried to put it inside my action like this

```
storeExpense(context, params){
    axios.post('api/expenses', params)
    .then( response => {
        context.dispatch('getExpenses')
        this.$swal(
            'Success',
            'Expense has been updated!',
            'success'
        )
    })
    .catch( error => {
        context.commit('errors', error.response.data.errors)
        //console.log(error.response.data.errors);
    })
}
```

but nothing happened because it is on the action file. Should I call it inside my component like this?

```
this.$store.dispatch('storeExpense',this.expense)
     .then( response => {
      this.$swal(
         'Success',
         'Expense has been created!',
         'success'
)
```

Any idea on how can I implement this? Thanks

Im beginner in vuejs and vuex.

Comment: Have your action `return` the promise created by Axios. Then your last code snippet (in the component) will actually work. See [Returning Promises from Vuex actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165766/returning-promises-from-vuex-actions)

Comment: Have your action return the promise created by Axios - by using resolve?

Comment: No, literally add a `return` before `axios.post`, eg `return axios.post(...)`. Axios creates a promise already so you don't need to create a new one. See https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#composing-actions and the other post I linked above

Comment: It is working inside the .then but i don understand why .catch is not catching the errors

Comment: I tried to put a sweetalert inside the .catch but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I think the key question is that "this" may be not the "this" you want in store module, "this" in store module is different from "this" in components.
So change the way you want to alert

1. import swa in your store module

   import Swal from 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js'
2. do alert when axios compolete use code below

   Swal.fire({
       title: 'Error!',
       text: 'Do you want to continue',
       type: 'error',
       confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
     })
3. never forget import swa's css file in main js