# Vuejs conditionally Redirect after post based on store data

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

**Hindsight 20:20 edit - this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165766/returning-promises-from-vuex-actions) was one that addresses the real underlying issue, which isn't apparent when encountering the problem below. Leaving this question/answer for posterity.**

I have a VueJS front end with a Django REST API backend with several Endpoints.

User Flow that I can't get to work:

1. Users input numeric data via a form, and presses a button. Data is in local variable in BasePage.vue
2. Data service (AddNormal) is called which takes local variable and POSTs to correct API
3. Response data from API (including pass/fail) is set to Vuex Store via setter.
4. Based on store variable - page needs to redirect to pass or fail page.

**How do I conditionally redirect to either a Pass page (with further actions) or a fail page based on this Vuex Store variable?**

`BasePage.vue`

```
<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
name: "basepage",
components: {
  ...stuff...
},
data() {
return {
  data: [],
 };
},
methods: {
...mapActions("results", ["addNormalResults", "addVPCResults"]),
getStats() {
  const payload = this.buildDataPayload;
 //this calls the store page to update the store with response data
  this.addNormalResults(payload).then(() => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  console.log('normal finished');
  const result = this.normalResults;
  console.log(result); //always is empty
  });
},
clearData() {
  this.data = [];
}
 },

  computed: {
...mapState("results", ["normalResults"]),
}
```

`results.js store page`

```
import statsEndpoints from '../../services/statsEndpoints'

const state = {
'normalResults': 'empty',
'vpcResults': 'empty',

}

const getters = {
normalResults: state => {
    return state.normalResults
},
vpcResults: state => {
    return state.vpcResults
}
}


const actions = {
addNormalResults({commit}, payload) {
    statsEndpoints.postNormality(payload)
        .then(response => {
            commit('addNormal', response)
        })
},
addVPCResults({
    commit
}, payload) {
    statsEndpoints.postVPC(payload)
        .then(response => {
            commit('addVPC', response)
        })
}
}

const mutations = {
addNormal(state, response) {
    state.normalResults = response
},
addVPC(state, response){
    state.vpcResults = response
}
}

export default {
namespaced: true,
state,
getters,
actions,
mutations
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning Promises from Vuex actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165766/returning-promises-from-vuex-actions)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out and answering my own question for posterity:

The real issue is asynchronous actions for the vuex. Its asynchronously finishing the "addNormalResults" action while the commit is happening because the Promise of the statsEndpoints.postNormality **was not being returned** to the function inside my Vue component.

If the Promise is returned in the action, one can use `.then( ()=> {do stuff}` to resolve the Promise and then do the `do stuff`.

The change to `results.js store page`:

```
const actions = {
    addNormalResults({commit}, payload) {
    return statsEndpoints.postNormality(payload) //notice the return
        .then(response => {
            commit('addNormal', response)
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can call a action in your store when it is success it's value is set to true and when there is error it's value set to false and then call a getter inside your component where you are calling you function and use that getter to redirect the user like this

```
if(sucess){
      this.$router.replace({
                path:'to success path',query:{
                  id:your query 'optional'
           }
        })
}else{
this.$router.replace({
                path:'to error path',query:{
                  id:your query 'optional'
           }
        })
}
```