# Components lifecycle with axios data

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

In the application I'm working on, I have a component loading data and storing them in a store. To do so, I have implemented the created function and a computed function like this :

```
computed: {
  initiatives: function () {
    return this.$store.state.initiatives.initiatives
  }
},
created () {
  this.$store.dispatch('initiatives/getInitiatives')
}
```

This allows to have an initiatives variable available from the component. To define a specific initiative, I have a variable like this :

```
data: function () {
  return {
    cinitiative: {}
}
```

What I want to do is to initialize the cinitiative variable with a random object from the loaded objects stored in this.initiatives. When I do it in the created function :

```
created () {
  this.$store.dispatch('initiatives/getInitiatives')
  let iindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(this.initiatives.length))
  this.cinitiative = this.initiatives[iindex]
}
```

I have this error :

```
TypeError: "this.cinitiative is undefined"
```

And I have the same error when I try to do the same from the mounted function. Where should I do it ?

Comment: I think you need to return a promise, check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165766/returning-promises-from-vuex-actions

Comment: Perfect! it worked, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As `created` hook is executed only once and `initiatives/getInitiatives` depends on a Promise, you should **await** for this, like:

```js
async created () {
  await this.$store.dispatch('initiatives/getInitiatives')
  let iindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(this.initiatives.length))
  this.cinitiative = this.initiatives[iindex]
}
```

But actually a **best practice** is turn `cinitiative` into a computed property, which is reactive to `initiatives`:

```js
computed: {
  initiatives: function () {
    return this.$store.state.initiatives.initiatives
  },
  cinitiative: function () {
    let iindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(this.initiatives.length))

    return this.initiatives[iindex]
  },
},
```