# How to wait on Vuex state initialization from a view component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, promise, vuex

I'm building a Movie website to practice on VueJS. During app initialization, I get a list of movie genres from 3rd-party API. Since this list is needed in several components of the app, I manage and store it via Vuex, like so:

**main.js:**

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App),
  created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('getGenreList')
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Vuex's **index.js**:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    genres: []
  },
  mutations: {
    setGenreList (state, payload) {
      state.genres = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async getGenreList ({ commit }) {
      try {
        const response = await api.getGenreList() // axios call defined in api.js
        commit('setGenreList', response)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Now, in my Home view, I want to retrieve a list of movies for each genres, something like this:

**Home.vue:**

```
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import api from '../api/api'

export default {
  name: 'home',
  data () {
    return {
      movies: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      sections: state => state.genres
    })
  },
  async mounted () {
    const moviesArray = await Promise.all(
      this.sections.map(section => {
        return api.getMoviesByGenre(section.id)
      })
    )
    this.movies = moviesArray
  }

}
</script>
```

The issue here is that, on initial load, `sections===[]` since genres list hasn't been loaded yet. If I navigate to another view and come back, `sections` holds an array of genres objects as expected.

**Question:** How can I properly wait on `sections` to be loaded with genres? (since the `getGenreList` action isn't called from that component, I can't use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40167499/4926605) method)

I was thinking in implementing the movie list retrieval in a Watcher on `sections` instead of in `mounted()` but not sure if it's the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it is right approach, that's what watchers are for.

But if you only can... try to do actions like this one inside one component family. (parent passing props to children, controlling it);

You can read this article, about vuex - https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/should-i-store-this-data-in-vuex/.
It will maybe clarify this idea. Just simply don't store in vuex everything, cause sometimes it' does not make sense

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch - for this one preferably you should use `immedaite` flag on watcher and delete mounted. Watcher with immedaite flag is kinda, watcher + created at once