# Vuex Action never resolve

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I'm having problem to make my Action resolve the promise.
I've read what looks like the most relevant posts.

[Returning Promises from Vuex actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165766/returning-promises-from-vuex-actions)

I want to know when my action is finished, then my component can start doing other stuff.
The problem is, the Action never returns the Promise.

**myComponent.vue**

```
 methods: {
  loadUrls() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getUrls').then(result => {
      console.log("getUrls result", result)
    })
  },
```

vuex.js

```
  actions: {
    getUrls() {
      console.log("getUrls")
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("setTimeout in")
          resolve("Resolved!")
        }, 1000)
      })
    },
```

That's my console log:

[image]

I've used the "setTimeout" to make as simple as possible the problem. In real life I call an API.

I do not need to rely on the result of this promise. I'm aware about it. I use Vuex as the source of truth, but I need to track when the event in completed.

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-butterfly-5hw8p?file=/src/main.js

Comment: @User28, thanks for that. It helped me to ensure that my code was correct. I've modified your project to double check I was not missing any fundamental VueJs concept, and all worked. https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-nightingale-n24xx
The problem was on my environment . I needed to clean and restart everything .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! It worked after I delete my dist Folder, close VSCode and open a new Chrome instance using the new build local host URL.

Thanks @User-28. I saw his shared code and realised nothing was wrong with my code. Then I start looking at my environment.

My very first code didn't have Promise Resolve in the action. I compiled and I was testing it.

Then I found [Returning Promises from Vuex actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165766/returning-promises-from-vuex-actions) which explained how to use the Promise in it. I compiled and I was TRYING to test it. Never success. Somehow the code without the Promise was always there. After clean up Dist folder, Close VS code and use a new Chrome instance, the new code was in place and worked.
I'm still don't know the actual problem, but at least it can keep going forward now.