# Can't access specific state property in Vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

My store's state object has 3 properties: `user_id`, `favorites`, and `posted_states`

This is my state object:

```js
state: {
        favorites: [],
        user_id: null,
        posted_states: []
  
      },
```

I have an action that queries my database, and sets the `user_id` property to the returned value.
The problem is, in another action, when I try to access the `user_id` property, it always returns null. Something weird I've noticed is, if I try to log the actual `state` variable, it shows the 3 properties I mentioned, and the `user_id` property correctly shows the id, and is not null.

[image: Output of console.log]

[image: Code for above screenshot]

As you can see, accessing the state directly always returns null. Even weirder, if I try to access `state.user_id` from a different action, it returns the correct `user_id` and is not null.

This is the action where I get the `user_id`:

```js
get_current_user_id ({commit, state, dispatch})
        {
          Nova.request().get('/nova-vendor/favorites-tool/get_current_user_id')
          .then((response) => {
              // handle success
              if (response.data) {
                commit('set_user_id', response.data)
              }
  
          })
```

This is the mutation where I set the `user_id`

```js
set_user_id(state, payload) {
          state.user_id = payload
        },
```

I don't think the issue is with the mutation, or the action itself honestly. I have also tried skipping the mutation entirely and setting it directly, which did not work. I have tried using a getter instead of accessing it directly, and also tried separating my component into a parent-child where the parent dispatches the action to set the user_id and the child dispatches the action that needs the user_id, under the assumption that this would eliminate a race condition if it even exists (however, I don't believe this is a race condition either.)

Comment: Have you tried using `getters`?

Comment: I have, I forgot to add that in my post.

Comment: In what other action are you trying to access user_id and when is that action called?

Edit: I would suggest typing debugger at the point where you call the action to fetch the user_id from the backend and the action where you are trying to access user_id. I guess you are trying to access it before you have the backend response

Comment: Can you show sample code of the retrieval methods you mentioned - one that succeeds in returning user_id and one that fails?

Comment: I don't have a specific code for "retrieval", I have an action that is supposed to set the state of the user_id once. The "success/failure" depends on the action that tries to access the state.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this in case anyone runs into this issue - the issue was indeed a race condition. I fixed it by writing the action that commits the `user_id` as a promise and then changing the second action that requires the `user_id` to only dispatch when the promise resolves, following this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40167499/12462293